# Correctly setting up custom route for SEO friendly blog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm looking to have a SEO friendly route for my blog using MVC 4.  I have looked over several stackoverflow articles and tried to utilize the advise but, I still cant get it to work properly.

What I am try to do is when someone clicks on one of the blog post, the route displays:
blog/{blogCategory}/{blogTitle}, for example "blog/cleaning/how-to-remove-stains".  I am missing something important.  I have included the controller, view and route. I have two questions:

1. Why when I pass the blogTitle ("The rain in spain") to the controller it comes in with hyphens and spaces?  I want to be able to take the title and run it through a function to make it URL friendly and put it back out to be displayed in the route.
2. Why does the route only partially work?  Instead of displaying blog/{blogCategory}/{blogTitle} it displays blog/{blogCategory}?querystrings see example below: blog/uncategorized/the%20-rain%20in%20-spain%20-falls%20-mainly%20on%20the%20-plains?id=2. (Note: uncategorized is one of the categories)

ROUTE CONFIG:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.Canonicalize().NoWww().Pattern("([a-z0-9])([A-Z])", "$1-$2").Lowercase().NoTrailingSlash();

            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            "Blog",
            "Blog/{blogCategory}/{blogTitle}",
            new { controller = "Blog", action = "Details" }
            ).RouteHandler = new Spotless_Interiors.Models._GlobalClasses.HyphenatedRouteHandler();

            // Original route map
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ).RouteHandler = new Spotless_Interiors.Models._GlobalClasses.HyphenatedRouteHandler(); 


        }
    }
```

VIEW:

```
@model Spotless_Interiors.Models.MultiModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Blog";
    ViewBag.Separator = " | ";
    ViewBag.Path = Request.Path;

}


@section menuLeft {
    @Html.Partial("_BlogMenu")
}
@Html.Partial("_TitleBlockPartial", Model.Company)

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    <div class="blog-links">            
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Blog", new { DT_Stamp = @DateTime.Now })
        @ViewBag.Separator
        <a href="@Url.Action("Meta-Tag-Editor", "Dashboard", new { pageName = (string)ViewBag.pageName, path = (string)ViewBag.Path })" >MetaTag</a> 
        <hr />
    </div> 
}

<div id="blog">
    @foreach (var item in Model.PagedPosts)
    {


            <h1>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.PostID, blogCategory = item.Category.CategoryName, blogTitle = item.Title }, new { @class ="blog-title" }) </h1>  

            <div class="full-width">
                <div class="blog-category">  
                    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName) |  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DT_Stamp)</h2> 
                </div>
                <div class="blog-links"> 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Read More >>", "Details", new { id = item.PostID, blogCategory = item.Category.CategoryName, blogTitle = item.Title }, new { @class ="blog-links" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="full-width">

            </div>
                @Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(item.TruncatedBody.Replace("<img ", "<img style = 'width:100px' ")))


            <div class="ribbon" style="clear:both"></div>            

    }
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
// GET: /Blog/Details
        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0, string blogCategory = "", string blogTitle = "")
        {
            pageName = "Blog Details";
            ViewBag.pageName = pageName;
            var multiModels = _globalClasses.Standard(ViewBag.pageName, Request.Path);

            ///multiModels.Post = db.Posts.First(i => i.PostID == id);
            multiModels.Post = db.Posts.First(i => i.PostID == id);
            multiModels.PostComments = db.PostComments.Where(i => i.PostPostID == id).ToList();


            blogTitle = _globalClasses.UrlFriendly(blogTitle);


            if (multiModels.Post == null)
            {                
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(multiModels);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your custom extension methods `Canonicalize`(?) and custom route handlers mess things up.

Concerning ASP.NET MVC this is enough:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(name:"Blog", url:"Blog/{blogCategory}/{blogTitle}",
                    defaults:new {controller = "Blog", action = "Details"});

    routes.MapRoute(name:"Default", url:"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults:new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
}
```

And controller:

```
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(string blogCategory, string blogTitle)
    {
        return Content(string.Format("category: {0}, title: {1}", blogCategory, blogTitle));
    }
}
```

For path `/blog/my%20category/my%20title`, you get correct response `"category: my category, title: my title"`.